# How to have variable update for each instance of for-each loop?

Tags: visual-studio, for-loop, variables, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a for-each loop that goes through a file directory. These files are transaction information from different clients. When there is an error with a file (i.e. can't be processed), the Event Handler is to send an email to the client notifying them. There is a SQL task that uses an existing variable (Client ID from the file) that queries a table to get the Client's email address. I created a variable for the Client Email. I want to make this update each time the for-each loop is run, since each file will have a different value for the client email variable.

How can I ensure this?

Inside the for-each loop, there are three data flow tasks that could conceivably "error" and that's when I will be sending these notification emails. Will I need to scope a variable for each of the three executables within the loop for the Client Email? Or can I scope a single variable in the for-each loop?

I understand this may be a bit confusing so please let me know if you have any questions.

[image: For Each Loop Flow with Data Flow Tasks]
[image: Event Handler Flow]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put the client email function in the Foreach loop itself in order to accurately tie it to a specific file.